# Relation between carrier frequency and data transfer rate?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is there a relation between the frequency of electromagnetic waves and the rate at which it can carry information? If yes, then what it is and why it is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_modulation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_capacity. @brucesmitherson: neither AM nor FM are anywhere close to the physical limit, for that one needs to have error correction codes in place.

Comment: got me agaian haha!

Comment: There is also MIMO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO. Counting the number of available channels for a given bandwidth is not as trivial as our grandfathers assumed naively.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that you can't change the signal faster than the frequency of the wave then the frequency sets an upper limit on the number of changes in the signal per second.

In fact you can send information faster than this with some clever coding schemes if you are able to measure the amplitude/phase of the signal accurately.

Comment: If you use amplitude modulation that's faster than the "carrier", then your carrier isn't what you thought it was :) For example, I can amplitude modulate a zero frequency wave at amplitude modulation frequency $\Omega$, but then the signal is $\cos(\Omega t)$ which is hardly zero frequency any more.

Comment: Can you give an example of a clever scheme that transmits information faster than the carrier frequency by measuring amplitude accurately?

Comment: @DanielSank: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_frequency-division_multiplexing . If you have WIFI or almost any wireless or cable service, you are using it, right now. This is a typical engineering question, though, and it should be closed as such.

Comment: @CuriousOne I fail to see how this sends data at a higher rate than the carrier.

Comment: @DanielSank: Then you need to read the theory.

Comment: I think I understand that my original comment is foolish @CuriousOne, but one hardly has to resort to complicated modulation systems to see why. A simple square wave digital bit stream can be thought of as a system with a carrier at 0Hz (and a sinc function PSD, incidentally), but of course in the absence of any noise this system can send data as fast as it wants.

Comment: @DanielSank: You were asking for an example of a system that can exceed the carrier frequency by measuring amplitude and phase accurately and I gave you one. It's not even a complicated one. OFDM is as simple as they come (it's basically Fourier transforms).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41029/discussion-between-danielsank-and-curiousone).